# Three js animate blender model with material colors

Tags: three.js, blender

I have an exported (three js json format) blender model. The model have a few material with colors. If i use THREE.MorphAnimMesh and THREE.MeshPhongMaterial the animation is working fine but no material colors. If i use THREE.MeshFaceMaterial it have colors but animation not working. 
The question is, how can i animate with material colors from the model js file?

animation working but no colors. the model is white:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ morphTargets: true, morphNormals: true, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, shading: THREE.SmoothShading, perPixel: true }  );
var meshAnim = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, material );
```

model have the material colors but animation not working:

```
var material  = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial({ morphTargets: true, morphNormals: true, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });
var meshAnim = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, material );
```

here is the model js file: http://speedy.sh/rs39u/skeleton-0.js

btw, i saw the flamingo.js file from the examples. It have a morphColors object but if i know right i cant export this from blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Maybe someone can use it:

```
for (var i=0; i<geometry.materials.length; i++) {
    geometry.materials[i].morphTargets = true;
}
var material  = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial({ morphTargets: true, morphNormals: true, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });
var meshAnim = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, material );
```